# Send a kill signal to self

Tags: c++, linux, signals

I have a C++ code that runs a linux command, I want to simulate segfault i.e. **SIGSEGV** while executing that linux command from by C++ code.
So my code looks like this

```
int main(){
    string cmd = "some linux command that should throw seg fault";
    execute_linux_comand(cmd); // Want to simulate segfault coming while executing this command
}
```

What should I put in "cmd" so that it can send **SIGSEGV** to the sub-process created by calling this function?

Comment: A search for "bash SIGSEGV" leads to [this question on codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4399/shortest-code-that-raises-a-sigsegv), which has an 11-character bash solution. (There's a 4-character bash solution, but it's more cryptic.)

Comment: What does `execute_linux_comand` do? If it starts a sub process to execute `cmd`, you could probably `kill(pid, SIGSEGV);`

Comment: What do you mean by "send SEGSEGV to my function"?  You do not send signals to a function, you send them to a process.

Comment: execute_linux_admin() creates a subprocess and executes the linux command supplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending kill signal to self can by done by putting this command

```
kill -9 $$
```